# Почему java не хочет прочитать этот фрагмент кода?

Tags: java

```
Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите слово из 5-и букв: ");
if (str.hasNext()) {
    if (str.next().length() == 5) {
        System.out.println("sdf");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ну я же просил из пяти букв!");
    }
} else if (str.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Это не слово!");
}
```

Так вот, если я ввожу цифры он принимает это за string. Этот фрагмент будто просто не учитывается

```
else if (str.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("Это не слово!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Scanner.hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) возвращает истину если на входе есть любой знак, в том числе и цифра.

Второй блок здесь никогда не выполнится, т.к. если на входе есть число, то есть и знак (любое число можно считать как строку, не всякую строку можно считать как число).

Попробуйте поменять условия местами:

```
if (str.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Это не слово!");
} else if(str.hasNext()) {
    //что-то тут
}
```

Еще замечание в блоке `hasNextInt` Вы ничего не считываете, соответственно при следующем вызове `hasNextInt` снова вернет истину.

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @BlackBlur Пожалуйста! Если проблема решена, [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (слева от ответа должна быть галка).